# ADO Not Allowing User to Create A New Task Within The To Do Column or Move the Flow of an Item Without Opening the Item

Tags: azure, azure-devops, task

I am a support Anaylst that works with a group of developers on ADO. I am having trouble changing the status or adding a task to an item without having to open the story or bug up in full then adding the progression or adding the task. Others on my team are able to do this by clicking on the dropdown within the box without the need to open. Same for the Tasks, in the To Do column there is a green plus where they click to add the task. I have to take the long route and create a child as a task and do this long form. It is quite time consuming. I have read on some posts online that this is becuase i have the Stakeholder role and that it needs to be basic in order for me to do this. Which would be great to try but my other teammates havethe stakeholder role as well and they are not having the same problem as I. I asked our ADO admin and he informed me that this is not a permissions issue and hinted that it could be a browser setting. I am using the latest version of Chrome but, this happens with Firefox and IE as well. I didn't try edge seeing outi it is powered by Chrome.

If anyone has any idea what this is and how I can fix this it would be awsome to go back to work and let them know what it was and what the fix is. They are all really busy, as am I, plus it's really not keeping me from doing my job...but if there is anything that I hate, it is wasting time and that's what I'm doing while taking several extra steps to do something.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> adding a task to an item without
> having to open the story or bug up in full then adding the progression
> or adding the task.

For this issue, you need to check if `Task` is enabled in the **Annotations** of **Settings** .

[image]

[image]

> having trouble changing the status , in the To Do column there is a green plus where they click to add the
> task. I have to take the long route and create a child as a task and
> do this long form.

For this issue, if the member is a `stakeholder` access level user，the `New Items` option will not be displayed.  For details ,please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/permissions-access-boards?view=azure-devops#boards-feature-access).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is a global setting though. This is only affecting my user and not the others on the team. The Admin now thinks it could be a bug in ADO. Not that he's trying to figure out what that is for me, I'm determined to figure it out though.

Comment: Are you and your colleagues in the [same team group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwXIY.png)?